# Postgres crashes when selecting from view

Tags: postgresql

I have a view in Postgres with the following definition:

```
CREATE VIEW participant_data_view AS
SELECT participant_profile.*,
        "user".public_id, "user".created, "user".status, "user".region,"user".name, "user".email, "user".locale,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM message_log WHERE message_log.target_id = "user".id AND message_log.type = 'diary') AS diary_reminder_count,
        (SELECT SUM(pills) FROM "order" WHERE "order".user_id = "user".id AND "order".status = 'complete') AS pills
FROM participant_profile
    JOIN "user" ON "user".id = participant_profile.id
;
```

The view creation works just fine. However, when I query the view `SELECT * FROM participant_data_view`, postgres crashes with

```
10:24:46.345 WARN  HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@172d19fe marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)                                                                            c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925083) suggests to me that it might be an internal assertion that causes it to crash.

If I remove the `diary_reminder_count` field from the view definition, the select works just fine.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix my view, or change it so I can query the same data in a different way?

Note that creating the view works just fine, it only crashes when querying it.

I tried running `explain (analyze) select * from participant_data_view;` from the IntelliJ query console, which only returns

```
[2020-12-08 11:13:56] [08006] An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
[2020-12-08 11:13:56] java.io.EOFException
```

I ran the same using `psql`, there it returns

```
my-database=# explain (analyze) select * from participant_data_view;
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Looking at the log files, it contains:

```
2020-12-08 10:24:01.383 CET [111] LOG:  server process (PID 89670) was terminated by signal 9: Killed: 9
2020-12-08 10:24:01.383 CET [111] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: select "public"."participant_data_view"."id", "public"."participant_data_view"."study_number", <snip many other fields>,
"public"."participant_data_view"."diary_reminder_count", "public"."participant
2020-12-08 10:24:01.383 CET [111] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

Comment: That's not a PostgreSQL error message. Please try and run the query from a `psql` and attach whatever error you see there and in the DB log.

Comment: Your connection pool marks this query as "crashed".  I don't see any evidence that Postgres itself crashed. Can you run `explain (analyze) select * from participant_data_view;`? (note the `analyze` which makes it run the query but not return the results) If yes how long does it take? Maybe the connection pool uses a query timeout which makes it fail

Comment: Then please check the Postgres server's log file

Comment: Does `select * from message_log` work properly? Could it be that `message_log ` is a foreign table?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Queries on that table work fine, although I haven't tried select * specifically

Comment: I solved the problem by rewriting the view using a WITH expression to extract the same data. It's not ideal, but it'll do for now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Found the log file, added to question

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, the Linux kernel out-of-memory killer killed your query because the system ran out of memory.

Either restrict the number of database sessions (for example with a connection pool) or reduce `work_mem`.

It is usually a good idea to set `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` in the kernel and tune `vm.overcommit_ratio` appropriately.

Comment: This is pretty surprising to me, since Postgres is running directly on my dev machine. Is there something about the view that would explain that much memory use? I didn't think a simple count and/or sum would be that expensive. And the view should only have about 1200 rows at the moment.

Comment: Who else but the kernel would kill your backend on your development machine? The number of result rows is not significant in that context. You could look at `EXPLAIN` output and see if there is a larger hash, bitmap or sort.

Comment: That's part of the problem: The Explain query also crashes, as detailed in the question

Comment: I am talking about `EXPLAIN` without `ANALYZE`.

Comment: I saw this on Kubernetes - no hints in the logs what so ever, but increasing the memory allowance helped